# css background-image displaying wrong on android

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a 1920x1080 big background picture. I want to use it on my landing page as the full background-image. I tried it on my pc in chrome, firefox, opera and it worked fine, even on my iPad in chrome. But not on my android phone in my app Chrome app, the image is there but it doesnt fill out the whole page, it just ends in the middle of the screen (portait mode). I want to fill out the whole page background with this image.

```
body{
background-image: url(bg_2.jpg);
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this for my mobile app:

```
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
```

and the css:

```
body {
   background: transparent url(../icons/texture.png) no-repeat center center;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

best

M

Comment: **"maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"** - Somewhere puppies are crying. Please don't use this...it's not recommended and provides a **very** poor user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
body {
    background-image: url(bg_2.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Change "cover" to "contain". But I'd prefer cover to contain after seeing the result.